# C#: Finding a Missing Dependency

Tags: c#, exception, dependencies

I'm getting this error message whiile running a Webservice I'm working on.  it builds, but this happens when I Invoke:

```
File or assembly name (Redacted).Framework, or one of its dependencies, was not found
```

The stack trace shows that between my code and the target of the exception, there are 3 referenced DLLs and 4 layers of System.Reflection.  How do I find what was passed into the method that threw the Exception, or at least find what dependency it's looking for and where it's looking for it?

I do not have access to the code nor symbols for the referenced DLLs that lie between my code and the Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DependencyWalker helps in finding out which DLLs are missing.

Comment: Actually, I ended up finding what I needed by checking the DLL manifest via ildasm.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the exception and/or inner exception of it.

You can remote debug the process to see exception details. If it is a dll, you can add a sleep or better, wait until a debugger is present : "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached" and then Attach to it and wait the exception. If the error is at start then fusion is probably the only way.

Fusion is also very nice.

Eric